# Trying to use Python variable names in psycopg2 queries

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am writing part of a Python program where I query a PostgreSQL table called stockNames and use the results to print information based on user input. stockNames has the following layout:

```
company     stockTicker     industry
Starbucks   SBUX            Food/Beverage
...
```

I also have a series of Python print statements as follows (brief variable assignments shown as well):

```
stockChoice = input('Select a stock ticker: ')
stockPrice=soup.find(class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")

print('\n' 'Company Name:')
print('Stock Ticker: ',stockChoice)
print('Industry: ' '\n')
print('\n' 'Date: ',)
print('Stock Price: ',stockPrice.text)
```

My goal is to query the company name and industry based on the stock ticker the user inputs (stored as stockChoice in the Python program but existing as stockTicker in the PostgreSQL table stockNames) and print that information in the print lines above. I tried including the stockChoice variable in the psycopg2 query, but received the following error:

```
cur.execute('SELECT company,stockTicker,industry FROM stockNames WHERE stockTicker=stockChoice;')

column "stockchoice" does not exist
```

The error makes sense since stockchoice isn't a column in my original stockNames table, but I'm not sure how to navigate this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is why documentation is written, [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Right now the query hitting the database is: `SELECT company,stockTicker,industry FROM stockNames WHERE stockTicker=stockChoice`. Where  `stockChoice` is taken to be an identifier since it is not single quoted and since Postgres lower cases identifiers that are not double quoted `stockChoice` becomes `stockchoice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a placeholder for it:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT company,stockTicker,industry FROM stockNames WHERE stockTicker = %s', (stockchoice,))
```